# Create a draw() function inside other function in Javascript Processing

Tags: javascript, function, draw

Ok, so I have this piece of code:

```
 var a = 0;
 var left = random(width);
 var right = left +50;
 var pos = left;
 var isLeft = true;

 var draw= function() {
    background(255, 0, 0);
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    strokeWeight(2);
    stroke(255, 255, 255);
    ellipse(pos,400-a,10,10); 
    a=a+0.5;
    if (isLeft === true) {
        pos +=0.5;
    }
    if (pos === right) {
        isLeft = false;
    }
    if (isLeft === false) {
        pos -=0.5;
    }
    if (pos === left) {
        isLeft = true;
    }
 };
```

Basically all it does is create a bubble that floats upwards while moving left and right just a little bit. My idea is to make it so that this only happens/starts when I click the mouse. But I don't seem to know how. I am still learning how to code. Anyone can help me produce the desired effect.

Thanks you and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want it to happen if you click anywhere then this example should work for you:

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", draw, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your function is called `draw` and your button's ID is `draw-start`, then add an event listener to the button which calls the function.

```
document.getElementById('draw-start').addEventListener('click', function(){ draw(); }, false);
```

However, if you want to start the animation if the click happens on the canvas in which you are drawing, and canvas ID is `draw-canvas` then,

```
document.getElementById('draw-canvas').addEventListener('click', function(){ draw(); }, false);
```

Comment: Ok, I do not understand this. Maybe it's because I'm trying to use this on the khanacademy.com course. There's this challenge where you only need to place fishes when you click, which is easy, but I wanted to take it to the next level, and maybe the khanacademy just does not have this ... I don't know. Are you familiar with the website ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [onclick event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) to make javascript execute on a click.  However, your draw function is also broken.  This shows you how to call the javscript when something is clicked:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>


function draw() {
   alert('draw stuff')
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="draw()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

You can try it [here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sg6smwn/)

Comment: Ok, I do not understand this. Maybe it's because I'm trying to use this on the khanacademy.com course. There's this challenge where you only need to place fishes when you click, which is easy, but I wanted to take it to the next level, and maybe the khanacademy just does not have this ... I don't know. Are you familiar with the website ?